# net/http ignoring system proxy settings

Tags: go

I'm using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to debug HTTP requests, but it seems that Go's network stack ignores the system proxy settings (on OSX) and the requests are not logged.

How do I tell Go that the requests should use the proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get proxy info using [ProxyFromEnvironment](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment) function. Then you create http client using transport (represented by RoundTripper interface) that has info about your proxy settings:

```
var PTransport http.RoundTripper = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment}

client := http.Client{Transport: PTransport}
```

Then you just do http request using the info transport gets from passed function to `Proxy` struct field. Proxy info will be taken from `$HTTP_PROXY` environment variable.

Answer (score 7):

I just had this exact issue, and the accepted solution did NOT solve it for me. That's because my `$HTTP_PROXY` environment variable was not set!

I was able to solve it by setting up my environment variables as per indicated here: http://www.bonusbits.com/wiki/HowTo:Setup_Charles_Proxy_on_Mac Then once the variable was set correctly, I didn't even need to apply a custom `Transport` to my client. It worked with the default transport.

Perhaps because I'm using a custom shell (zsh) this didn't happen automatically. However what's interesting is that python would correct appear in Charles Proxy in the same shell while Go would not. Updating my .zshrc (or whatever shell or profile you are using's config) to export the appropriate variables worked.

Comment: all i had to do was export the variables as listed in your link and it worked